# How does the nosetests sqlalchemy plugin work?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, nosetests

The python unit testing framework called nosetest has a plugin for sqlalchemy, however there is no documentation for it that I can find. I'd like to know how it works, and if possible, see a code example.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that this plugin is only meant for unit testing SQLAlchemy itself and not as a general tool. Perhaps that is why there are no examples or documentation? Posting to the SQLAlchemy mailing list is likely to give you a better answer "straight from the horse's mouth".